# How to get phpunit CLI options inside my test class

Tags: phpunit, symfony

Is there a way to check, inside my test class, if a specific option was passed to the phpunit CLI, especially the option `--debug`.

The reason for this, is to be able to create the symfony kernel with the debug mode enabled or not.

```
public function setUp()
{
    self::bootKernel(["debug" => true|false]);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by using `$_SERVER['argv']`

I found this solution inside the symfony code base `KernelTestCase::getPhpUnitCliConfigArgument`

```
/**
 * Finds the value of the CLI configuration option.
 *
 * PHPUnit will use the last configuration argument on the command line, so this only returns
 * the last configuration argument.
 *
 * @return string The value of the PHPUnit CLI configuration option
 */
private static function getPhpUnitCliConfigArgument()
{
    $dir = null;
    $reversedArgs = array_reverse($_SERVER['argv']);
    foreach ($reversedArgs as $argIndex => $testArg) {
        if (preg_match('/^-[^ \-]*c$/', $testArg) || $testArg === '--configuration') {
            $dir = realpath($reversedArgs[$argIndex - 1]);
            break;
        } elseif (0 === strpos($testArg, '--configuration=')) {
            $argPath = substr($testArg, strlen('--configuration='));
            $dir = realpath($argPath);
            break;
        } elseif (0 === strpos($testArg, '-c')) {
            $argPath = substr($testArg, strlen('-c'));
            $dir = realpath($argPath);
            break;
        }
    }

    return $dir;
}
```